# Angular *ngFor isn't reactive when list is updated

Tags: angular

I'm having troubles getting reactivity in the child components when i update the list in the parent component.

The data i have is pretty nested and looks like this

```
{ //projectList
  "projects": [
        {
            "name": "project",
            "displayed":true,
            "layers": [
                {
                    "name": "child_1",
                    "displayed":true
                    "layers": [
                        {
                            "name": "child_1_1",
                            "displayed":true
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "child_1_2",
                            "displayed":true

                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

in the parent component I use *ngFor like this:

```
 <li *ngFor="let project of projectList">
                <child1
                    *ngIf="project.displayed"
                    [project]="project"
                ></child1>
  </li>
```

the child1 component is also using another child2 in order to go deeper inn the structure if it contains more layers. So the child2 component uses recursion to create more levels, but i think the problems occurs way before that.

What I'm trying to do here is to filter the list and set displayed:false in the nested structure from the parent component. I want this change to get detected by child1 and child2, why doesnt it happen?

(the shown examples are simplified alot)

One solution to trigger changedetection is to do a projectList = copy(projectList) after i change the displayed attributes, but this introduces some unwanted behaviour

the filter function (simplified alot):

```
  private setfilteredProjectList() { //STARTS HERE
        this.projectList?.forEach((projectArray) => {
            projectArray.layers.forEach((layer) => {
                    let filterSearch = this.filterSearchString(layer);
                    layer = filterSearch.layer;
                          
            });
        });
    }

 private filterSearchString(layer: Layer) {
        if (!layer.layers?.length) {
            if (this.search === '') {
                layer.displayed = true;
            } else {
                if (
                    layer.layername
                        .toLowerCase()
                        .startsWith(this.search.toLowerCase())
                ) {
                    layer.displayed = true;
                } else {
                    layer.displayed = false;
                }
            }
        } else {
            layer.layers.map((l) => {
                let childFiltered = this.filterSearchString(l);
                return childFiltered.layer;
            });
        }
        return { layer };
    }
```

UPDATE: i see a great mistake i made; used forEach instead of map in setfilteredProjectList()...

Comment: Have you tried using `trackBy`?
https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/angular-ngfor-trackby/

Comment: Can you share the filter code?

Comment: @OwenKelvin yeah i've tried trackBy where i used a id attribute from the list objects

Comment: @PMO1948 I've updated the post with a simplified version of my filtermethods

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an issue with `reference` types (arrays and objects) where we have to change the location of RAM to ensure that change detection takes place and when you have nested objects and arrays, it becomes cumbersome and annoying but try this.

```
private setfilteredProjectList() { //STARTS HERE
       // assign projectList to a new array
        this.projectList = this.projectList?.map(project => { // the map in both cases 
            const layers = project.layers.map(layer => {     // creates a new location in
               let filterSearch = this.filterSearchString(layer); // memory and ensures
               return filterSearch.layer;                         // change detection 
            });                                                   // to take place
            return {
              ...project, // spread the old project object
              layers,     // update the layers value
            };
        });
    }
```

Comment: The problem with this method is that it changes the object reference to projectList which causes all the child components to rerender. Is there a way to go throught projectList and its element which doesnt create a new reference?

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way to get predictable change detection without changing the reference of reference types. Changing the reference guarantees change detection will run.

Comment: Thats too bad, cause I don't want the child components that is generated from the list to get initialized again when another child is getting changed. From this example I only want the change detection to detect that displayed is set to either false or true, not the whole list

Comment: What you can do is create a new instance variable/object called `displayChildren = {}` with id/name as the key and `true/false` as the value (`displayChildren = { '1': true, '2': false }`) and update this object accordingly every time projects changes. You can then do `<child *ngIf="displayChildren[project.name]"` />`. I think that can get you what you want.